# creating a new vector layer from a part of the current one

Tags: qgis

I am using qgis 2.6 for the first time. As I was using 2.2 previously, it was easy for me to create a new vector layer from a part of the current layer with the help of option "save selection as a new vector layer" from Layer menu. But I don't seem to find this in qgis 2.6.

Answer (score 3):

Since QGIS 2.6 this option is nested in Save As tool just tick the box *Save only selected features*:

[image]